# Can't send e-mail using fake sendmail in wamp

Tags: php, sendmail

I have been doing this for hours and can't get it to work, many comments in the tutorial said it works like a charm but I can't really make this work.

I have done all the steps here http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/ and read all the comments with problems other users encountered and also used the solutions replied.

What I see on the apache error log is this

```
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:47 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4120
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:47 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:48 2012] [notice] Child 4120: Child process is running
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:48 2012] [notice] Child 4120: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:48 2012] [notice] Child 4120: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:48 2012] [notice] Child 4120: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Nov 27 05:19:48 2012] [notice] Child 4120: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I also have tried it on my other computer and it has the same error log. I have disabled my firewall and also critically followed the steps on the tutorial.

Comment: Have you checked the settings for sendmail are loaded correctly? Have a look at what the phpinfo() tells you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the previous answer. Thanks everyone for your suggestions to improve my answer. Here is my answer: The phpmailer has a file called class.phpmailer.php. Then in the `function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body)` the code goes as follows:

```
global $error;
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = 'gmailusername';  
$mail->Password = 'gmailpassword';           
$mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->IsHTML(True);
    $mail->Body=$body;
//$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
} else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';
    return true;
}
```

Then just call the function where ever you want as:
`smtpmailer($to, $from, $headers, $subject, $message);`

Oh and prior to this make sure php_openssl extension is enabled.

I hope this answer of mine was helpful. :)

Comment: Put it as a comment to the question.

Comment: +1 because phpMailer is a much better solution than php's built-in mail function, but balanced down to zero by a -1 because you really didn't give any information; an answer like this needs to be backed up with a link to the phpmailer site and some explaination of why it's better.

Comment: @habeebperwad - users with low rep can't post comments. don't vote down because of that; instead flag it so a moderator can convert it into a comment.

Comment: +1 for the answer afer it was updated. For the link to phpmailer download and further usage examples, see my previous answer to another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail/12302354#12302354